# VS2013 + TFS: Forcibly disable IntelliTrace?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, msbuild, mstest, intellitrace

We are using Visual Studio 2013 on our dev machines and TFS build agent. IntelliSense is not supposed to be available in the version we're using (Premium) but on the build agent it is somehow running anyway with MSTest (verified by IntelliTrace.exe being observed running as a child process of vstest.executionengine.exe and writing large quantities of *.iTrace files to C:\Windows\Temp). This is both consuming disk space and significantly slowing the test runs down by making them artificially disk bound.

The problem is that there doesn't appear to be any way of preventing IntelliTrace from running; this edition of VS2013 doesn't show it in the Tools->Options list, so we can't use the UI-based approach to disable it. Our custom workflow passes /p:EnableIntelliTrace=false as an MSBuild argument, to no effect.

Does anybody know of a way we can disable it by other means while still having the build & test run pass? (Registry, file renaming, etc). We don't foresee ever having to run IntelliTrace on the machines in question.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this @T2PS?

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete `/p:EnableIntelliTrace=true` instead of  `/p:EnableIntelliTrace=false` to disable the IntelliTrace run during MSbuild.

If this is no effect on your build agent. It seems related to the VS on your build agent. Try to disable the settings of testsettings file, and try again. 
Detail steps you can refer this link: [How to disable / turn off IntelliTrace on TFS MsBuild server?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2ca15ff5-ca61-4a2a-8359-72fee87513c0/how-to-disable-turn-off-intellitrace-on-tfs-msbuild-server?forum=vsdebug)

Moreover, there should be the option of with IntelliTrace with VS2013. Please check the info of this blog [IntelliTrace using Visual Studio 2013 Preview](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/943/intellitrace-using-visual-studio-2013)
[image]

Comment: This section does not appear in the options list for any of our VS2013 installs. I'm combing through the build workflow but can't seem to find anything that is setting EnableIntelliTrace=true. Our test .runsettings file does not mention IntelliTrace at all.

Comment: It works well with my VS2015 after disable the IntelliTrace in the options. You may try the workaround: update your VS2013 to VS2015 and disable the option in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Since VS 2012 IntelliTrace and other data colelcotrs are configured in *.testsettings* configuration file. If this file is not explicitly given, the default one is used. I'm not sure but it seems to me that in your case IntelliTrace is enabled in a default configuration. My suggestion is to try the following steps:

1. Add *.testsettings* file to a solution. To do so right click the solution in VS. Then select *Add -> New item...* and find *Test Settings*.
2. A new configuration file will be added to your solution and by default IntelliTrace should be disable. If you double click this file, a new window with various options will be displayed so you can verify if the configuration is correct.
3. Tell *MSTest* to use your own *.testsettings* file. It can be done with */testsettings* parameter.

Comment: We're using a .runsettings file rather than a .testsettings file, as this was recommended for VS2013. Looks like IntelliTrace can't be configured outside of .testsettings, but MSDN adds the caveat that adding one will slow the test run down; as we're trying to improve performance here, we'll have to try this and find out.

Answer (score 0):

You still can use .runsettings to disable IntelliTrace (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635153.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It's not documented anywhere. Just copy DataCollector for IntelliTrace from the .testsettings file and disable all collections.

Comment: Actually you can try to add .runsettings file without any configuration for IntelliTrace. I wonder whether IntelliTrace is still running even though it's not explicitly specified to do so.